# How to use whereMatchesKeyInQuery with pointer to class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I call them tables but in the code they are actually just classes. 
I got table of users (class that extends ParseUser)
I got table TableAClass (class that extends ParseObject), and
I got table TableBClass (class that extends ParseObject)
B contains pointers to MyUserClass and to TableAClass

```
ParseQuery<MyUserClass> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(MyUserClass.class);


ParseQuery<TableBClass> secondQuery = new ParseQuery<TableBClass>(
                    MyInstallsClass.class);
```

now the key part, I can't query like this

```
query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery( "objectId", "myuser_id",secondQuery);
```

because 'myuser_id' is not an String it is a Pointer to MyUserClass
How should I make this query work without adding additional String columns with of String type that will contain the objectId

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still relevant, anyway, you may do `secondQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("myUserId","objectId",query);`

Answer (score 0):

use `whereMatchesQuery` in case of pointer

```
query.whereMatchesQuery("obj_pointer", inQuery);
```